# jQuery Masonry fixed / prepositioned element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

i have a navigation element inside a jquery masonry layout and i would like to fix it to a specific position lets say right top. is it possible to do that so every other element gets positioned around it?

something like preposition the navigation..

this is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ftqTr/

right now i'm trying to position an empty element where the navigation is. but the size of the div boxes are random.. so a fixed position for the fake navigation or another solution would be awesome!

thanks in advance

Comment: yes it might be possible if you provide some sample code

Comment: added a jsfiddle example. do you have an example of a fixed position element inside masonry?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a feature that has been often requested. I call it "corner stamp." I've created a modification that you can use:

https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/105
http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/M8EYn/embedded/result,js,css/

---

*update Mar 25, 2016*

This feature has been implemented as the [`stamp` option in Masonry v3](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#stamp)

Comment: @desandro I am having problem while prepending element, the element is getting prepended before cornerstamp, and corner stamp is moving forward, pls help